# Swift. Google map view shows questionmarks instead of letters

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Why is my google map view showing questionmarks instead of letters:

[image: screenshot of iphone]

My code for implementing the map view:

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(-33.86,
        longitude: 151.20, zoom: 6)
let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
self.view = mapView

let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20)
marker.title = "Sydney"
marker.snippet = "Australia"
marker.map = mapView
```

Comment: Code seems to be the same with the official guide, so this is really weird! is this only showing up on the emulator or on actual devices as well? Other configurations done aside from the snippet shared?

Comment: The snapshot is from my actual device.

In my appDelegate i have:

    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("(my APIKey)")

Answer (score 0):

[v1.8.0 (May 2014)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/releases?hl=en#version_180_-_may_2014) has an update regarding an issue raised similar to you. The [ticket raised](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5228) suggests it may have something to do with the language settings. So, you can check out if the language setting was changed and hopefully it solves the issue. Also check if you're using the latest version of the Maps iOS SDK.

Comment: any idea on how to fix this, I've been searching around and it dosen't quite  say anywhere how to do it?